# Checker texture addon question?

Tags: random

I am trying to make a node setup where i have

1. Transparent Tex
2. Principal BSDF
   these both are going through the mix shader .
   I want to control the Factor of the mix shader with a chekered texture .
   But i want to add a step to the checkered texture , i would like to randomly assign the
   checkboxes to both the shaders, as of now when i connect the Chk texture to factor , it
   assigns the textures to the tile and the  and mortar, i would like some grids to be transparent and some assinged to the Principal BSDF.
   How do i achieve this , i couldn't find a random value node to control this or don't know the way to do this being a noob.
   any help is appreciated.
   Best
   Z

Comment: please add an image how it should look like. thx.

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an output of *Brick Texture* to a *Color Ramp* node with *Constant* type enabled:

[image]

In *Color Ramp*, you can adjust how many tiles should be shaded/transparent

Comment: Ah thank you for the quick reply :) Cant thank you enough good serr !
[![Quick dirty test ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO3HR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uO3HR.png)

Comment: If you would set _Color2_ to black instead of grey, you would have a wider variety of tiles. Of course it is not so important since you are using the _Color Ramp_ for the distribution.